# How to use different network interface for Cassandra inter-node communication?

Tags: cassandra, network-interface

I have four Cassandra nodes deployed. I have a Java application which acts as a client to the Cassandra cluster. Now, I want to see if I can use **different network interfaces** for the **Inter-node communication** and the **Data transfer**.

Can you shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. For inter-node communication you can specify IPs/interfaces via `listen_address` (or `listen_interface`, but not together) ([conf](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11/conf/cassandra.yaml#L600)), and for client->Cassandra communication - `rpc_address` (or `rpc_interface`) ([conf](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11/conf/cassandra.yaml#L677))...

If necessary, you may need to set `broadcast_address` & `broadcast_rpc_address` as well, but it depends on the topology of your cluster.

Comment: What are the other factors? Only specifying two different interfaces can do the job?

Comment: It should work for simple clusters, but for multi-DC clusters, for example, on AWS you may need to specify different broadcast addresses, etc. See for example this description: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/config/useCasesSingleMultiNodeAddress.html

Comment: If they are in the  same datacenter, do I still need to provide external IPs for listen-address and rpc-address?

Comment: no... usually the listen_address is the private address, and if the external access is required, then broadcast addresses is used in addition.

Comment: And, when I comment out the line mentioning the rpc_address, and, specify the rpc_interface as eth0, the server is failing to start.

Comment: you need to specify either `rpc_address` or `rpc_interface` (let me update the answer)